# Modifying DictField in multiple documents together stored in Mongodb using mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am working with a mongo database model building using mongoengine. I want to modify `DictField` by the result created in another function

```
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
import marshmallow_mongoengine as ma
db = MongoEngine()

class TestData(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=50, required=True,unique=True)
    num1 = db.IntField()
    num2 = db.IntField()
    ml_proc = db.DictField()
    hum_proc = db.DictField()

class TestDataSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = TestData
```

The sample data in database will be like below

**Sample Data**

```
[{
    "name" : "david",
    "num1" : 5,
    "num2" : 4,
    "ml_proc": {"sm": 7, "prod":12}
},
{
    "name" : "john",
    "num1" : 1,
    "num2" : 4
},
{
    "name" : "dune",
    "num1" : 5,
    "num2" : 5,
    "ml_proc": {"sm": 7, "prod":15}
},
{
    "name" : "jan",
    "num1" : 3,
    "num2" : 4
}]
```

Out of 4 documents in sample data, 2nd and 4th document have missing field `ml_proc`. The fields in `ml_proc` are `sm` and `prod` which are created from fields `num1` and `num2` calculated in another function defined as

```
import pandas as pd
    def calc(data):
        data["sm"] = data["num1"].apply(lambda x : x+2)
        data["prod"] = data["num2"].apply(lambda x : x*2)
        return data
```

I know its weird to think why this function is necessary but this is a very simple one for my requirement. The number of documents I am handling will be thousands at a time. Thats why i used pandas dataframe for processing. So my doubt is how to update Dictfield in  multiple documents using result generated from pandas data processing

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance

**Database**
Note: Dont take too much conc on values. This is just a sample image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
db.collection.update({
   "ml_proc": {
     $exists: false
  }
 },
 [
  {
    $addFields: {
      ml_proc: {
        sm: {
          $sum: [
            "$num1",
            2
          ]
        },
        prod: {
          $sum: [
            "$num2",
            2
          ]
        }
       }
      }
    }
 ],
 {
  multi: true
})
```

Explained:

1. Match only documents where "ml_proc" do not exist
2. addFields the "ml_proc" calculated based on num1 & num2 from same document
3. Update all matched documents with the missing field "ml_proc".

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I8A1NnZ_DUV)

Comment: Thanks for replying. The sample given is too simple. My calculating function is defined in another function and the result returns are list of dictionary having sm and prod. That function handles pandas dataframe to get the result sm and prod. For this simple sample, your answer works. My doubt is how to update dictfield having multiple fields in multiple documents from the data generated as a result from pandas dataprocessing. Upvoting your answer Hope you will upvote my question too.

Comment: Thanks ! Upvoting your question , btw starting from 4.4 there is a possibility to add custom aggregation JS function: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/function/ if you dont need to use pandas ...

Comment: The real function does lot of machine learning process. Cleaning of raw data, filtering, applying ML etc. its a complicated system. Cant replace that. Thats where I am stuck

Comment: In that case you better do it from python , fetch the doc  execute calc(data) and store back the doc. And to be faster you may need to add some multithreading...

Comment: Okay . Thanks for the attempt to help me :)

Comment: Can you help me with this aggregator function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71650858/aggregation-function-for-counting-of-duplicates-in-a-field-based-on-duplicate-it