# Aggregation function for Counting of Duplicates in a field based on duplicate items in another field

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am using mongoengine as ORM with flask application. The model class is define like

```
class MyData(db.Document):
    task_id = db.StringField(max_length=50, required=True)
    url = db.URLField(max_length=500,required=True,unique=True)
    organization = db.StringField(max_length=250,required=True)
    val = db.StringField(max_length=50, required=True)
```

The field organization can be repeating and I want to get the count of duplicates with respect to values in another field. For example if the data in mongodb is like

```
[{"task_id":"as4d2rds5","url":"https:example1.com","organization":"Avengers","val":"null"},
 {"task_id":"rfre43fed","url":"https:example1.com","organization":"Avengers","val":"valid"},
 {"task_id":"uyje3dsxs","url":"https:example2.com","organization":"Metro","val":"valid"},
 {"task_id":"ghs563vt6","url":"https:example1.com","organization":"Avengers","val":"invalid"},
 {"task_id":"erf6egy64","url":"https:example2.com","organization":"Metro","val":"null"}]
```

Then I am querying all the objects using

```
data = MyData.objects()
```

I want a response like

```
[{"url":"https:example1.com","Avengers":{"valid":1,"null":1,"invalid":1}},{"url":"https:example2.com",Metro":{"valid":1,"null":1,"invalid":0}}]
```

I tried like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$organization",
      "count": [
        {
          "null": {
            "$sum": 1
          },
          "valid": {
            "$sum": 1
          },
          "invalid": {
            "$sum": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

but I am getting an error

```
The field 'count' must be an accumulator object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  "$group": {
  "_id": {
    k: "$organization",
    v: "$val"
   },
  "cnt": {
    $sum: 1
   }
  }
 },
 {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    k: "$_id.k",
    o: {
      k: "$_id.v",
      v: "$cnt"
    }
   }
  },
 {
   $group: {
    _id: "$k",
    v: {
      $push: "$o"
    }
  }
},
{
  $addFields: {
    v: {
      "$arrayToObject": "$v"
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    new: [
      {
        k: "$_id",
        v: "$v"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "$addFields": {
    "new": {
      "$arrayToObject": "$new"
    }
  }
},
{
 "$replaceRoot": {
   "newRoot": "$new"
 }
}
])
```

Explained:

1. Group to count
2. Project for arrayToObject
3. Group to join the values
4. arrayToObject one more time
5. project additionally
6. arrayToObject to form the final object
7. project one more time
8. replaceRoot to move the object to root.

P.S.
Please, note this solution is not showing the missing values  if they do not exist , if you need the missing values additional mapping / mergeObjects need to be added

[playground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c2M_IiZGOqe)

Option with missing values ( if possible values are fixed to null,valid,invalid) :
just replace the second addFiedlds with:

```
   {
   $addFields: {
     v: {
    "$mergeObjects": [
      {
        "null": 0,
        valid: 0,
        invalid: 0
      },
      {
        "$arrayToObject": "$v"
      }
    ]
   }
  }
 }
```

[playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wqNx-mxUEE5)

++url:

[playground3](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ch67dcT9v6l)

Comment: oke , added option2 with missing fields  count shown as 0 , this version works in case only null,valid and invalied are the possible options ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more doubt. Is it possible to add the `url` field to the required dictionary(updated the response required in question). I know i am asking too many things. I am new to this and also learning in parallel. I am trying to get that. Not succesfull yet

Comment: updated my answer with ++url in playground3

Comment: Thanks again. Is there any tutorial where I can master this framework. Deserves High score for the answer. Brilliant.

Comment: Best are the official trainings from mongodb , they are free of charge , this one specially related to agg: https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about

Comment: Its of great help. Thanls. I have to go in detail through that :)

Comment: Seeking one more help. Is it possible to solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71860512/updating-and-adding-on-multiple-documents-using-pymongo with aggregation pipeline

Comment: Need a bit more help. Can you help me with this query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066438/adding-multiple-fields-to-documents-in-mongodb-using-pymongo