# Adding multiple fields to documents in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a sample collection of documents in mongo db like below

```
[{"name":"hans","age":30,"test":"pass","pre":"no","calc":"no"},
{"name":"abs","age":20,"test":"not_pass","pre":"yes","calc":"no"},
{"name":"cdf","age":40,"test":"pass"},
{"name":"cvf","age":30,"test":"not_pass","pre":"no","calc":"yes"},
{"name":"cdf","age":23,"test":"pass"},
{"name":"asd","age":35,"test":"not_pass"}]
```

For some documents the fields `pre` and `calc` are not present. I want to add those two fields to the documents which dont have those fields with value `null` for both `"pre":"null", "calc":"null"`.

The final document should look like

```
[{"name":"hans","age":30,"test":"pass","pre":"no","calc":"no"},
{"name":"abs","age":20,"test":"not_pass","pre":"yes","calc":"no"},
{"name":"cdf","age":40,"test":"pass","pre":"null","calc":"null"},
{"name":"cvf","age":30,"test":"not_pass","pre":"no","calc":"yes"},
{"name":"cdf","age":23,"test":"pass","pre":"null","calc":"null"},
{"name":"asd","age":35,"test":"not_pass","pre":"null","calc":"null"}]
```

I tried this way but didnt work.

```
db.users.update({}, { "$set" : { "pre":"null","calc":"null" }}, false,true)
```

Comment: I think you should use `db.users.aggregate` function to make updation of your db, please refere to this link this will be helpful for your case i hope https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to run this query for every missing field that you have , for example for pre:

```
db.collection.update({
pre: {
    $exists: false
  }
},
{
 "$set": {
   "pre": null
 }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dWu8z2wvDsR)

Answer (score 2):

Thinking that you need an update with the aggregation pipeline.

And use `$ifNull` operator.

```
db.users.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "pre": {
        $ifNull: [
          "$pre",
          "null"
        ]
      },
      "calc": {
        $ifNull: [
          "$calc",
          "null"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
false,
true
)
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zp2_DxeO2b0)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting an error 
`TypeError: upsert must be True or False`

Comment: Not PyMongo developer, but your code should be: `db.users.update({}, [...], false,  true)`.  which `[...]` is the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: In pymongo this is not working. Unfortunately I am working with pymongo. `        $ifNull: [
          "$pre",
          "null"
        ]` This is considered as an array in pymongo. This replaces every `pre` and `calc` field with an array object